# CodeIgniter Query Builder - Get data with date within next 2 days

Tags: php, query-builder, codeigniter-3

**Background:**

Users can create a booking. They can set a 'required by' date and time for said booking. This goes in to the db as a datetime format.

I have a page that needs to show bookings that are upcoming within the NEXT TWO days, and not after

**Issue:**

I am having trouble getting the data limited to within 2 days.

Currently I am able to get it to retrieve ALL upcoming bookings.

**Current Code**

```
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('nh_bookings');

    $this->db->where('nh_bookings.booking_req_by_date_time > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)');

    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: booking_req_by_date_time datatype ?

Comment: `where(... , '', false)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to do something like this:

```
$this->db->where('nh_bookings.booking_req_by_date_time >=', date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($start_date." 00:00:00")));
$this->db->where('nh_bookings.booking_req_by_date_time <=', date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($end_date." 23:59:59")));
```

Or:

```
$this->db->where("nh_bookings.booking_req_by_date_time BETWEEN ".date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($start_date." 00:00:00"))." AND ". date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($end_date." 23:59:59")));
```

Comment: Thank you! Took your initial answer, with 2 WHERE statements, modified it a bit, and it now works like a charm!

Changed them to:
    $this->db->where('nh_bookings.booking_req_by_date_time >=', date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $start_date));
    $this->db->where('nh_bookings.booking_req_by_date_time <=', date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $end_date));

Comment: @TomPearce Glad that it helped you! Happy Coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->where('nh_bookings.booking_req_by_date_time < DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL 2 DAY) AND nh_bookings.booking_req_by_date_time > NOW()');
```

retrieves items from now till next two days.

also remember that where() method has third argument $escape, which is TRUE by default. this argument can cause escaping of Mysql functions, so they don't work properly